# assert_select to test raw or html_safe unescaped content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, escaping, functional-testing, actioncontroller

In a Rails 3.2.8 controller test, I'd like to use an `assert_select` to control the content an unescaped field rendered in my view using the `raw` or the `#html_safe` method :

```
<div id="summary">
    <%= raw @doc.summary %>
</div>
```

But in my test, both these assertions fail :

```
# Fixture loading in doc variable, get :show, assert_response ...
assert_select('#summary', doc.summary)
assert_select('#summary', doc.summary.html_safe)
```

If my summary is something like `<p>Stuff:</p><ul><li>Stuff1</li><li>Stuff1</li></ul>`, then the test tells me, for both lines, that :

```
<"<p>Stuff:</p><ul><li>Stuff1</li><li>Stuff2</li></ul>">
expected but was
<"Stuff:\n  \n    Stuff1\n    Stuff2">
```

When in test mode, it seems to render the view with `\n` instead of HTML tags, as if escaping for a CLI display.

But when I launch the server and display my page in the browser, this part is rendered with HTML tags and no `\n`.

Is it a bug in the controller test rendering engine ? Do you know how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
assert_select('#summary', :html => doc.summary)
```

This way, whatever transformation applied to the DOM-selected content is also applied to the second arg before comparison.

---

***NB: Beware of the way you write your fixtures though.***

The following syntax:

```
doc:
  summary: |
    <p>Stuff:</p><ul><li>Stuff1</li><li>Stuff2</li></ul>
```

gets a final extra `\n` from the assert_select, compared to :

```
doc:
  summary: <p>Stuff:</p><ul><li>Stuff1</li><li>Stuff2</li></ul>
```

I have no idea why this occurs, but it makes the assert fail.

Comment: Adding a `strip` fixes the `\n` issue. So it would be `assert_select('#summary', html: doc.summary.strip)`